# android pass rating (1-5 stars) to play store via deeplink

Tags: android, google-play, parameter-passing, deep-linking

I’m trying to pass rating (1-5 stars) to play store via deep links, is it possible?

```
  val uriBuilder = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details")
                                .buildUpon()
                                .appendQueryParameter("id", PACKAGE_NAME)
                            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
                                data = uriBuilder.build()
                                setPackage("com.android.vending")
                            }
                            startActivity(context,intent, bundleOf())
```

Answer (score 1):

nope, this kind of injection isn't possible, but you may use official [Google Play In-App Review API](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the Google Play Review API to allow the user to review your app by displaying a dialog. You can find out more here: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review